# Is there a way for a bash script to re-run after a case selection?

Tags: bash

I just wrote a bash script to change PHP-cli and Apache PHP versions without having to manually run dismod or enmod etc etc, and for the script to restart Apache to make the changes, and being that the script uses a case statement, I have a problem in that when the code inside the choice is finished the entire script ends, ie:-

```
case $CHOICE in
1) do code;;
2) do code;;
esac
```

So when either choice of 1 or 2 is chosen, the script inside choices is executed, then the script is ended, but I want to restart the script unless the 'Cancel' button is pressed in the dialog box, ie:-

```
CHOICE=$(dialog --clear \
            --backtitle "$BACKTITLE" \
            --title "$TITLE" \
            --menu "$MENU" \
            $HEIGHT $WIDTH $CHOICE_HEIGHT \
            "${OPTIONS[@]}" \
            2>&1 >/dev/tty)
```

I have tried adding the script name as an extra line before the ;; but it still stops.

To give an idea, the code I have written is to big to post here, but I'll post it to pastebin and post the link here:-

https://pastebin.com/q2iH7Q2E

As can be seen, I had to add extra case lines at the end of the script, but I want to remove those and have the script rerun after any of the selections are made.

Comment: Put a loop around the code that prompts and executes the `case` statement.

Comment: So basically, I would add a 'do' before the Case and a 'done' after esac, right?

Nope, didn't work, I get syntax error near unexpected token `do'

Comment: You would add `while true; do ... done`

Comment: `do` is not a loop by itself, it's part of the syntax of `while` and `for`.

Answer (score 0):

Put a loop around all the code.

```
while :
do
    # all the code that should repeat goes here
done
```

Inside the loop you can use `break` to stop the loop.